# Memory Issues For Mac App

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am having an issue for the following method in my AppDelegate.

```
- (void)itemDiscovered:(PodcastShow *)show
{
    NSLog(@"%@", show);
    NSArray* newArray = [self.showArray arrayByAddingObject:show];
    self.showArray = (NSMutableArray*)newArray; //This line signals SIGABRT
}
```

I'm a fairly new with ARC and Objective-C in general. Obviously, there is a memory issue, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I've written a ton of code just like this and I've never come across an issue like this. Here is the showArray property:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *showArray;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `[self.showArray addObjectsFromArray:newArray]` or `[self.showArray addObject:show]`.

Also be sure that you are creating the mutable array by calling `self.showArray = [NSMutableArray array]` (or something similar) somewhere in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Why wouldn't you just add the new object to the showArray?

```
[self.showArray addObject: show];
```

Or am I missing something with the creation of the `newArray`?

Comment: The objects don't get added to the array if I do that. The app wont crash, but nothing happens. When I do it as shown above, it works about 10% of the time, the other times it crashes.

Comment: I worded that wrong. showArray is bound to an NSArrayController in the main nib file. I only see the changes in the interface when I do it as shown above.